# Separate variable from string

Tags: php

I've got 2 vars - $j and $r

In string "$jx$r" php sees $jx as variable, but "x" is a string.

Answer (score 9):

You need to reformat your string a litte:

Tis might be easier to read:

```
echo $j."x".$r
```

But if you want it in one string:

```
echo "{$j}x$r";
```

[`See the manual page for double quoted strings`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), there is also an explaination how the curly braces work.